# Exchange cmdlets from c#

Tags: c#, exchange-server, powershell-cmdlet

I need to run exchange cmdlets from a c# console application.

I followed the guide from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332449.aspx for a simple command with a single parameter

The cmdlets I need to run is:

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -server evs | Select servername, StorageGroupName,databasename,@{expression={$_.TotalItemSize.value.ToKB()}},ItemCount,mailboxguid
```

I cannot specify the field that I need after the `select` command and I don't know how I can pass the expression `@{expression={$_.TotalItemSize.value.ToKB()}}` to cmdlets.

Is there a way to do it in managed code?

Comment: Oooh,I so wish that you had gotten an answer to this question, other than the one to try Redemption.
I'm working on the same thing, and if I get an answer I'll be back here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the examples in the Exchange Management Shell SDK at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff326155(v=EXCHG.140).aspx?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Redemption library: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/

I'm not sure if it satisfies your specific requirements but it does expose a lot of information through managed code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Import-PSSession to move the remote session into a local powershell runspace.

Here are 2 methods.

[Powershell to Exchange 2013 - Restricted language mode error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856240/powershell-to-exchange-2013-restricted-language-mode-error)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/akashb/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-call-ps1-script-from-managed-code-using-remote-powershell-exchange-2010.aspx