# Powershell to Exchange 2013 - Restricted language mode error

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm working on a C# web service that will be deployed on an Exchange 2013 server. This service will be responsible for running powershell commands to configure Exchange.

I connect via a runspace created like this

```
const string shellUri = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/microsoft.exchange";
var uri = new Uri(_exchangeConnectionUri);
var credentials = (PSCredential)null; // Windows authentication
var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(uri, shellUri, credentials);
connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
```

Using this runspace I am able to run basic powershell commands on the server.

```
get-mailbox -ResultSize unlimited
```

But running more complicated commands gives me errors (this does work if run directly through powershell)

```
get-mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | where {$_.emailaddresses -like "*test.com"}

At line:1 char:43
+ get-mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | where {$_.emailaddresses -like "*test.com ...
+                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Script block literals are not allowed in restricted language mode or a Data section.

At line:1 char:44
+ get-mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | where {$_.emailaddresses -like "*test.com ...
+                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Property references are not allowed in restricted language mode or a Data section.

At line:1 char:44
+ get-mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | where {$_.emailaddresses -like "*test.com ...
+                                            ~~
A variable that cannot be referenced in restricted language mode or a Data section is being referenced. Variables that can be referenced include the following: $PSCulture, $PSUICulture, $true, $false, and  $null.
```

After searching I found that I might have to register a new PSSessionConfiguration and make sure the scripts are running under PSLanguageMode = FullLanguage. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18356159)

I tried to do this, but as soon as I change the shellUri to `http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/MyConfigName` I get the following error.

```
The WS-Management service cannot process the request.
Cannot find the MyConfigName session configuration in the WSMan: drive on the ComputerName computer.
```

Using the following shelllUri gave me the same error `http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Powershell`

This led me to try the following directly through powershell on the exchange server

```
> Get-PSSessionConfiguration | format-list -property name
result:
Name : MyConfigName
Name : microsoft.powershell
Name : microsoft.powershell.workflow
Name : microsoft.powershell32
Name : microsoft.windows.servermanagerworkflows

> $session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName MyConfigName -ConnectionUri $uri -Authentication Kerberos
result:
error "Cannot find the MyConfigName session configuration in the WSMan: drive on the ComputerName computer."

> $session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Powershell -ConnectionUri $uri -Authentication Kerberos
result:
error "Cannot find the Microsoft.Powershell session configuration in the WSMan: drive on the ComputerName."

> $session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $uri -Authentication Kerberos
result:
nothing, meaning $session variable set correctly
```

Like from the C# code, I can only use the Microsoft.Exchange configuration, but this configuration doesn't exist according to `Get-PSSessionConfiguration`, and the configurations that do exist in that list won't work.

I am now wondering how to add a configuration with FullLanguage that I can use when calling powershell from code.
I might also be completely wrong, and my issue is not related to PSSessionConfigurations at all, but then I still wonder why I can't see the Microsoft.Exchange configuration anywhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ended up getting support from Microsoft and they provided the following solution which works. Instead of connection via a remote powershell session, it is possible to connect to the local powershell and then import the remote session. Doing this fixes the issue.

Error handling not included in example below

```coffee
var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

object psSessionConnection;

// Create a powershell session for remote exchange server
using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    var command = new PSCommand();
    command.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
    command.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
    command.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", new Uri(_exchangeConnectionUri));
    command.AddParameter("Authentication", "Kerberos");
    powershell.Commands = command;
    powershell.Runspace = runspace;

    // TODO: Handle errors
    var result = powershell.Invoke();
    psSessionConnection = result[0];
}

// Set ExecutionPolicy on the process to unrestricted
using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    var command = new PSCommand();
    command.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy");
    command.AddParameter("Scope", "Process");
    command.AddParameter("ExecutionPolicy", "Unrestricted");
    powershell.Commands = command;
    powershell.Runspace = runspace;

    powershell.Invoke()
}

// Import remote exchange session into runspace
using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    var command = new PSCommand();
    command.AddCommand("Import-PSSession");
    command.AddParameter("Session", psSessionConnection);
    powershell.Commands = command;
    powershell.Runspace = runspace;

    powershell.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: thanks , had same problem.
Do I need to run those 3 [usings] for each script I wanna use ?

Comment: Running these 3 usings will prepare the runspace for other commands. The first one takes quite a while (around 5 seconds for us) so it is not feasible to run it for every command. We ended up saving the runspace in a static variable and reusing it for new commands.

Comment: Suddenly , I get 0 result on the first using-Invoke , therefore   psSessionConnection = result[0]; throw outOfRange expcetions , do you know why ?

Comment: I don't know much more about this sadly. It could be something with the server setup or authentication. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Btw, the code is missing semi-colon after the powershell.Invoke()  (I can't edit the post as it's below the limit of characters for edits).

Comment: Thanks @andreas, it really help me. First get a powershell session and import that session to execute cmd.